# how to move image near to table in GitHub markdown?

Tags: image, github, markdown

I just started using GitHub, and I can't find any information on how to move images in `README.md` files.

I managed to move the table beneath the image, but I want to put it next to the image.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, "RED" is the current position and "BLUE" indicates the desired position. [Link to the GitHub repository](https://github.com/DrMagPie/RTU-LD-Java/tree/master/LD2).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. At least I tried with a flexbox.

The closest you can get is putting the image directly inside the table and use HTML instead of MarkDown like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">kur:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">
            <img width="500px" height="auto" alt="screen shot 2018-01-10 at 21 42 01" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23652900/34791944-2951996c-f64f-11e7-91d1-25f6a88b24cf.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>x un y - šāviņa koordinātes (metros);</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>t - laiks (sekundes);</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>v0 - sākuma ātrums (metros sekundē);</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>α - leņķis zem kura izlido šāviņš attiecība pret horizontālu virsmu;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>g - brīvas krišanas paātrinājums (m/s<sup>2</sup>).</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Preview on GitHub:**

[image]

<kbd>**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9tko2unt/)**</kbd>

Comment: @Dr.MagPie Glad I could help :)